# Solve coupled polynomial differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, dynamical-systems

I have the following coupled differential equations:

$$\frac{dN_1}{dt} = p_1(N_1,N_2)$$
$$\frac{dN_2}{dt} = p_2(N_1,N_2)$$

Where $p_1,p_2$ are polynomials (in $N_1, N_2$). Is there a theory that deals with this kind of differential equations?

I'm hoping for something similar to the uncoupled case:
$$\frac{dN_1}{dt} = p(N_1)\Rightarrow N_1(t)=P^{-1}(t+c)$$
where $P^{-1}$ is the inverse function of $P(N_1) = \int\frac1{p(N_1)}$

Edit: The polynomials $p_1, p_2$ have both the following form:
$$p_1(N_1,N_2) = \sum_{i,j=0}^n a_{ij}N_1^iN_2^j$$
The coefficients $a_{0j}$(respectively $a_{i0}$) vanish, all other coefficients are non zero (negative and positive). $n$ depends on the application, typically between 2 and about 10. The range of the coefficients starts with $1$ and decreases "fast".

Comment: It's *much* more complicated than the uncoupled case. For general polynomials, there's hardly anything that can be said. Maybe you could write down what your specific polynomials are, and if you're lucky someone might be able to say something about that case.

Comment: The basic Ricatti equation can be written that way, $\dot N_1=1$, $\dot N_2=N_1^2+N_2^2$. It has no easy symbolic solution (but can be written as the quotient of named relatively nice power series) and blows up in finite time.

Comment: Sorry, my earlier comment may have been wrong. I will have to think a little more about this.

Comment: @HansLundmark Unfortunately the coefficients come from numerical processes, so there's not much to say about them. I would indeed need a general theory to solve this kind of problems.

Comment: @LutzL About the solution is known, that it has a (finite) global (if starting conditions are both positive) stable equilibrium. The differential equations describe population densities.

Comment: @Jürg Merlin Spaak : If the polynomials are defined from numerical processes, there is no raison to change of method: Solve the system of equations thanks to numerical calculus.

Comment: In any case, systems of this kind (with functions $p_1$ and $p_2$ that are not necessarily polynomials) are *continuous-time dynamical systems*, and to understand their behaviour one usually looks at the *phase portrait*. That might give you some terms to search for, but a full answer to this question could fill many books. When you have just two equations things are a little bit simpler than with three or more, since the phase portrait consists of curves in the plane, which can't cross each other, but it's still very complicated in general.

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak: Hans Lundmark didn't ask you to write down the coefficients. Just write down the equations and denote the coefficients with $a_n$ coefficients. The actual values are not important but rather the structure of the functions $p_1$, $p_2$ and maybe the range of the coefficients.